# Jetpack Compose – Why aren't buttonColors taking effect?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've defined my button composable like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PrimaryButton(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onClick: Callback, content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit) {
    val buttonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        contentColor = contentColorFor(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
    )
    Button(modifier=modifier, onClick = onClick, content=content, colors=buttonColors)
}
```

I've checked with the debugger and `contentColorFor` returns the appropiate color (white) (0xFFFFFFFF)

But I can't get to have the text on the button to be white.

Here's the preview

```kotlin
@Preview(name="Buttons")
@Composable
fun PrimaryButtonPreview() {
    MyAppTheme {
        Row {
            PrimaryButton(modifier = Modifier, onClick={}) {
                Text(text = "Sample")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result: [image: Result of preview]

Setting the `button = TextStyle(…)` results in a change on the text color but I'd like to set it from the button colors rather than having one unique color for the text

### Edit

After setting the button's text style color to unspecified it still doesn't work:

**Shapes are the default by the Android Studio project generator**

**Colors**

```kotlin
val mainBrown = Color(0xFFB4A996)
val primaryBrown = Color(0xFFC2A686)
val clearBrown = Color(0xFFAE967A)
val white = Color.White
val smokeWhite = Color(0xFFF3F3F3)
val gray = Color(0xFF9AA5AF)
val lightGray =Color(0xFFF1F1EF)
val darkGray = Color(0xFF4D5151)
val black = Color(0xFF4D4646)

val red = Color(248,113,113)
```

**Theme**

```kotlin
private val LightColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = primaryBrown,
    onPrimary = white,
    primaryVariant = primaryBrown, 

    secondary = white,
    onSecondary = primaryBrown,
    secondaryVariant = white, 
    background = darkGray,

    surface = lightGray,
    onSurface = black,

    error = red,
    onError = smokeWhite,
)

@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = LightColorPalette,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

**Typography**

```kotlin
val typography = Typography(
    h1 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W700,
        fontSize = 1.5f.rem,
        lineHeight = 2.rem,
    ),
    h2 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
        fontSize = 1.25f.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.75f.rem
    ),
    h3 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 1.5f.rem,
        lineHeight = 2.rem
    ),
    h4 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 1.25f.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.75f.rem
    ),
    body1 = TextStyle(
        color = black,
        fontSize = 1.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.25f.rem
    ),
    button = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 1.rem,
        color = Color.Unspecified,
        lineHeight = 1.25f.rem
    ),
    defaultFontFamily = ralewayRegular
)
```

Comment: Have you tried manually passing `Color.White`? The result is the same on a real run?

Comment: Yes, using `Color.White` as a `contentColor`  argument results in the same; setting the color manually on the text makes a difference. But to me looks like I am missusing the `ButtonColors` somehow

Comment: `MaterialTheme.typography.button` has priority over `ButtonColors`. If you remove explicit color from it, and use default `Color.Unspecified`, this will work

Comment: This is what I have (unspecified typography) and it doesn't work

Comment: I could not find any other reason in the source code, nor reproduce the problem. Please update your code to [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Let me add the Theme I don't have any other lines of code regarding styling…

Comment: Figured out that something's off with the typography as not setting it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My setup was fine except for the typography.

I was setting the color every time so that takes over how it should look from the `MaterialTheme`.

Don't set those values and let the framework handle it for you.

**Not working because I am setting (and forcing) `mainBrown` as the color**

```kotlin
val typography = Typography(
    h1 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W700,
        fontSize = 1.5f.rem,
        lineHeight = 2.rem,
    ),
    h2 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
        fontSize = 1.25f.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.75f.rem
    ),
    h3 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 1.5f.rem,
        lineHeight = 2.rem
    ),
    h4 = TextStyle(
        color = mainBrown,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 1.25f.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.75f.rem
    ),
    body1 = TextStyle(
        color = black,
        fontSize = 1.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.25f.rem
    ),
    button = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 1.rem,
        color = Color.Unspecified,
        lineHeight = 1.25f.rem
    ),
    defaultFontFamily = ralewayRegular
)
```

**Working**

```kotlin
val typography = Typography(
    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W700,
        fontSize = 1.5f.rem,
        lineHeight = 2.rem,
    ),
    h2 = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
        fontSize = 1.25f.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.75f.rem
    ),
    h3 = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 1.5f.rem,
        lineHeight = 2.rem
    ),
    h4 = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 1.25f.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.75f.rem
    ),
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 1.rem,
        lineHeight = 1.25f.rem
    ),
    button = TextStyle(
        
        fontSize = 1.rem,
        color = Color.Unspecified,
        lineHeight = 1.25f.rem
    ),
    defaultFontFamily = ralewayRegular
)
```